# CKeditor not working using Firefox 55.0.3. No errors. Works on all other browsers

Tags: firefox, ckeditor

Suddenly, my firefox won't display ckeditor edit boxes. This is even just using the sample code. Works great on all other browsers. No errors in the console. Firefox on my other machine 54.0.1 is rendering it just fine.

I can't find anyone else complaining about this. Maybe my firefox is just messed up or something?
[image: code and firefox vs. safari]

Comment: It's strange there is no errors, may be reason is because you are mixing http and https in you page ?

Comment: Nah, it's not a http/https issue. When I load this test up the live web server, it's https. Also, firefox throws warnings when it's refusing to load mixed content.

Comment: I noticed they have some issues with Firefox 55 on GitHub. https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/pull/927 . But for me, in Firefox 55.0.3 (Win) it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have also face this issue then found that skin.js file is missing. when I put this file my issue solved. now it is working in firefox.

you have to put skin.js in this location:

```
~/ckeditor/skins/yourthemename/skin.js
```

my theme was kama so my file location is:

```
~/ckeditor/skins/kama/skin.js
```

you can download this file from below url:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/master/skins/kama/skin.js
```

here, I used themename kama you can write your theme name and can download it.

Comment: We have a Angular 11 project. Ckeditor is saved in assets folder. If app loads Ckeditor from internet in index.html file, then everything works fine in every browser. If app loads Ckeditor from assets, then in Firefox component is loaded, but it can't be seen. The solution was to add editor_gecko.css in skis/moono-lisa/